# Graphical LCD With Atmega64

Tags: avr, wiring, programming, glcd

I have ATMEGA64 and LCM240128, The wiring is as below:

[image: wiring]

[image: wiring]

[image: fuse bit]
And my code is ( I'm using codevision):

```
    #include <mega64a.h>
    #include <glcd.h>
    #include <font5x7.h>
    #include <delay.h>

    void main(void)
    {
    GLCDINIT_t glcd_init_data;
    glcd_init_data.font=font5x7;
    glcd_init_data.readxmem=NULL;
    glcd_init_data.writexmem=NULL;
    glcd_init(&glcd_init_data);
    delay_ms(500);
    glcd_putcharcg(10,5,'c');
    while (1)
      {
      }
    }
```

It's controller is TS6963. The Lcd powers on but nothing is shown.
I tested the code in proteos and it works.
Is there any problem in my wiring or code?

Comment: I wouldn't know if the connection is done right, but are both ATmega and LCD at the same voltage?

Comment: I checked with multimeter and connection is as schematic and it's right connected.

Comment: They both are 5v

Comment: We don't even know which library that is and what pins it uses. Does the MCU run any code like blink a LED? Do you have a debugger to debug this? Is the Mega64 set to compatibility mode or normal mode, what are the fuse bits?

Comment: I used codevision's glcd library. And i think the code is right because it runs at proteos.

Comment: Pen pin is unconnected and so it is in normal mode.

Comment: So that leaves you with only one culprit left, the LCD.

Comment: Also, as justme said, tomorrow I have to test the normal mode of the microcontroller, such as setting up the blinking led.

Comment: I also attached fuse bits

Comment: Have you adjusted the contrast trimmer across its full range? If it's too far from the correct position, you may not see anything on the display. Adjust it until all character positions are black then back it off until the character positions are just discernably different from the non-character glass. Then test your code. Later, once your code is working, you can adjust the trimmer to your preferred contrast.